# Regex: How to match a decimal '.' if it's follow by or preceded by (or both) a '\d' decimal number

Tags: regex

Here's what I currently have, but it only works if the decimal is preceded and followed by a decimal.

```
^\$?(\d*?(?<=\d)\.?(?=\d)\d*?)$
```

So the string: `'$50.00'` matches, but `'$.50'`, and `'$50.'` don't match (I want them to)

I want to retrieve the matched decimal like '50.00' in a single group if possible so that I can grab the normalized value if there is a match.

Comment: Hm, are the $ and the dot required or optional?

Comment: Both optional because somebody can put '50.00', or just '50' or '$50.00' or just '$50'.

Comment: Isn't this really just a duplicate of your other question?

Comment: Not really. I figured out how to do what you guys showed me, but now I'm trying to understand look behinds look ahead and possibly the 'or' operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\$?\s*((?=\d*\.|\d)\d*(?:\.\d*)?)$
```

Comment: I tested that with $.1 and it didn't match.

Comment: That one caught it but it didn't match '1' because you were saying look ahead to see if a decimal follows.

Comment: OK, that's just pimp. The | operator was the number one thing I couldn't figure out. '^\$?\s*((?=\d*\.|\d)\d*(?:\.\d*)?)$' is the master regex for money as far as I'm concerned now. It allows all possible idiotic values (except for commas which make me barf). Thanks Lucero.

Comment: This matches `$.` as well as just `.`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^\$?(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$
```

It will match:

```
^\$?           # an optional $ at the begin
  (\d+         # one or more digits
    (?:\.\d*)? # followed by an optional decimal part
  |\.\d+       # or just decimal places without any leading digits
  )$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=^.*\d.*$)^(?:\$\s*)?(?:\d|,)*?\.?(?:\d?)*$

disallows:  
$  
.  
$.
<empty>  
<whitespace>

allows:
$50,000
$500
$0
50,000
500
0
.0
.00000000000
$50,000.000000
$ 5.
```

Answer (score 0):

Err, what about

```
^\$?(\d*\.?\d*)$
```

Comment: This will also match nothing or just `$`

Comment: 1+ Yours is actually pretty valuable too (does exactly the same thing except I don't want a match on empty because I'm raising errors before evaluating the group(1) result).